# PowerShell Class overload string[] seen as string

Tags: powershell

I have a class with an overloaded constructor:

```
MyClass([string] foo) { Write-Host "1" }

MyClass([string[]] bar) { Write-Host "2" }
```

When I run the following:

```
[MyClass]::new(@("my value"))
```

Id expect an output of "2". Instead I get "1". What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post your class definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are not passing a string array. You are passing an object array. Since an object array is not explicitly defined it tries to interpret it with the first constructor.

Using:

```
class MyClass{
MyClass([string] $foo) { Write-Host "1 $foo" }
MyClass([string[]] $bar) { Write-Host "2 $($bar)" }
}
```

e.g.:

```
PS C:\> $myValue = @("myvalue")
PS C:\> $myValue.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

PS C:\> [MyClass]::new($myValue)
1 myvalue
```

If you explicitly define it as a string array, then it works as expected:

```
PS C:\> [string[]] $strArr = @("strarr")
PS C:\> $strArr.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String[]                                 System.Array


PS C:\> [MyClass]::new($strArr)
2 strarr
```